# Problems with Android 11 and ICC

Tags: java, android

i have a problem with my Android Java App.

I used this code to obtain the ICC of the SIM:

```
List<SubscriptionInfo> sis = sm.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

// getting first SubscriptionInfo
SubscriptionInfo si = sis.get(0);

// getting iccId
return si.getIccId();
```

But now, when the phone update to Android 11, `si.getIccId()` returns `""`

Someone knows how to obtain the ICC in Android 11?

Ty

Comment: _" Starting with API level 30, returns the ICC ID if the calling app has been granted the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission, has carrier privileges (see TelephonyManager#hasCarrierPrivileges), or is a device owner or profile owner that has been granted the READ_PHONE_STATE permission. "_ says the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionInfo#getIccId()). Also _"READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission is only granted to apps signed with the platform key and privileged system apps."_ is said elsewhere in the docs. So, you probably can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, at this time it works:

```
TelecomManager tm2= (TelecomManager)getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
   
Iterator<PhoneAccountHandle> phoneAccounts = tm2.getCallCapablePhoneAccounts().listIterator();
PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle = phoneAccounts.next();

return phoneAccountHandle.getId().substring(0,19);
```

With TelecomManager and my first phoneAccount (Sim 1 in my mobile), i can take de ICC number of the PhoneAccountHandle with getId(). I have to split the string because it return the ICC number with a letter.

Comment: I have it implement it in my app but in android 13 its not working anymore